# Gettin a value from JSON object

Tags: jquery, json

I have a page that submits some data via AJAX to another page where it is processed and returned back using json_encode PHP function.

On my original page, in AJAX function, on success I get the data back and put it in alert to test like this:

```
success: function(data){
   alert(data);
}
```

The alert outputs in the following format:

```
{"id":2,"item":"my text string"}
```

No I need to grab each part of this object and do something with them using jQuery. How do I get them? I tried: data-> but it breaks my JS code... a bit confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, ensure the data you get are parsed as json by jQuery, using the `dataType` setting.

Then use `data.id` or `data['id']` to read the id parameter

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'someurl',
    dataType: 'json', // precise this
    success: function(data){
       var id = data.id;
       var item = data.item;
       alert(item);
    }
});
```

The `data['id']` construct is useful when your data are for example `{"some name":9}`.

Comment: If alert is giving you '{"id":2,"item":"my text string"}' you're not dealing with a JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

Your alert shows me that you don't have an object you're dealing with... but just a string.
You'll need to parse the data to a JSON object first.

http://jsfiddle.net/QNu9Y/

```
d= '{"id":2,"item":"my text string"}';


(function(data){
    var parsed = JSON.parse(data)
    alert(parsed.id)
       })(d)
```